# call PL/SQL procedures in alteryx

Tags: oracle, plsql, mapping, etl, alteryx

I want to call PL/SQL procedures only from alteryx. Just procedures nothing else, Some Procedures have dynamic parameters which will change while calling or execute the PROC.
I am not able to find any transformation where i can call only procedures.
I don't want to call from PRE/POST SQL command as i need to call from input or output transformation. I just want to call the PROC nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

usually

username.packagename.protocolname(parameter);

Comment: where i can give username.packagename.protocolname(parameter);

in which transformation?